# How do i solve the recurrence: $f(n)=F(n-1)+f(n-2)+1$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How do i solve the recurrence: $f(n)=F(n-1)+f(n-2)+1$?

My first attempt was to "guess" a private solution to the nonhomogenous which got me : $ f(n)= -1 $ and the corresponding is $F_n$ (fibonacci), so the exact solution is $ f(n)=F_n -1$?

was it right? thanks in advance.

Comment: These are good ideas, but without initial conditions you can't get an exact solution.

Comment: Consider the sequence $g(n)=f(n)+1$.

Comment: Presumably $F$ and $f$ are the same in your equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, inspired guessing is probably best; but if you want a systematic method: these three instances of the initial recurrence
\begin{align*}
-f(n)+F(n-1)+f(n-2)+1=0 \\
-f(n+1)+F(n)+f(n-1)+1=0 \\
f(n+2)-F(n+1)-f(n)-1=0
\end{align*}
sum to
$$
f(n+2) - f(n+1) -2f(n)+ f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 1 = 0.
$$
Subtracting this from its shifted version
$$
f(n+3) - f(n+2) -2f(n+1)+ f(n) + f(n-1) + 1 = 0
$$
yields
$$
f(n+3) - 2f(n+2) - f(n+1) + 3f(n) - f(n-2) = 0.
$$
This can be solved with the usual linear recurrence methods: its characteristic equation is $x^5 - 2 x^4 - x^3 + 3 x^2 - 1 = (x-1)^2 (x+1) (x^2-x-1)$, and so the general solution is
$$
f(n) = A + Bn + C(-1)^n + D\phi^n + E(-\phi)^{-n},
$$
where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ and $-\phi^{-1}$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1$.

Comment: Nicely done. A little different from separating the homogeneous part. +1